# Java Float max precise value

Tags: java, floating-point

Java `Float.MAX_VALUE` is `3.4028235E38`. At the same time the mantissa is 24 bits (with an extra hidden one) which can fit `16777215` value maximum. How is it capable of storing a value greater than the latter without losing the less significant digits?

Here is a kotlin [playground](https://pl.kotl.in/rhqwztVRJ) example

```
fun main() {
    val m = Float.MAX_VALUE
    val j = 16777215f
    val n = 1
    val k = j + n
    println(m)
    println(j)
    println(k)
}

3.4028235E38
1.6777215E7
1.6777216E7
```

Comment: maybe you are interested in reading about the [`Math.ulp()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#ulp(float)) method (or, on same Javadoc, `nextDown()` and `nextUp()`) - or some more *theoretical*, [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Looks like the arithments is in the play event when no math oprations are performed: have tried to declear a variable with `16777217f` value and got `1.6777216E7` printed out.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, that isn't possible. It does "loose its less significand digits". The second largest Java float value is not `Float.MAX_VALUE - 1`, but a lot less.